# Strobe iPhone background - NSTimer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nstimer

I want to set up a simple strobe of the background. I'd like to have a variable for frequency.
Is NSTimer the best way to do this? If so, how?

Thinking of maybe doing something like this:

```
LOOP OF SOME KIND() {
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
//DELAY - the amount is the frequency
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

FYI, I have a UISlider that's outputting values 0 to 255 for the frequency. So, 0 is no strobe. 255 is very fast strobe.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `NSTimer` you could use a `CADisplayLink` for that.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html

just save the timestamp when you last changed the color and if enough time passed change it again in the displaylink function.

Comment: +1 for suggesting CADisplayLink. If you don’t mind the inaccuracy, simply adjusting the display link’s `frameInterval` property, based on the slider value might do the trick without having to compare timestamps.